Bevel not rounding all corners
I have a cube where I selected 4 edges and used the Bevel tool. The corners at the top get rounded but not the ones at the bottom. Why is this the case?
https://streamable.com/5fnwvc


Have you applied the scale in Object mode (Ctrl-A > Scale) before bevelling? If that doesn't do it we'll need to see your Blend file which you can share via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

@JohnEason yes, I applied scale before bevelling. I attached the blend file as you suggested.

You have overlapping geometry:

Select all and merge( M  ->  B ) by distance to merge overlapping vertices and that should fix it.


It fixed it, thank you!
